# Can you create a logical volume to be within a logical volume?

Tags: partition, lvm, hp-ux

I'm using HP-UX.

Basically the problem is I need another logical volume to test EVFS. At the moment, I can't add another physical volume to the sever. And it seems that all of the physical volume on the server is allocated to be mounted at root. As far as I know, I can't reduce the root logical volume. Which means I have to create a logical volume within the root logical volume.

In Linux, I'd create a loop device, then pvcreate, vgcreate, lvcreate with it, but HP-UX doesn't support loop devices.

Is there a solution to this?

Here's a image of vgdisplay on my system.
[image]

As you can see, the size of lvol_evfs1 I tried to create has a size of 0.

Comment: LV inside an LV would be a strange feature. Why can't you shrink one of the three LV in the sole VG?

Comment: [Please do not post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).

Answer (score 2):

No, creating a logical volume inside a logical volume is not possible in HP-UX LVM.